# Swift Compiler Error : flutter code getting error

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, xcode14.3.1

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Compiling for iOS 11.0, but module 'PhoneNumberKit' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 12.0:
/Users/IBTechnologies/Fiver/Bruno/Code/bruno989-attachments/gengeni.com/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/PhoneNumberKit/PhoneNumberKit.framework/Modules/PhoneNumberKit.swiftmodule/x86_64-apple-ios-simulato
r.swiftmodule
/Users/gauri/Downloads/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/libphonenumber_plugin-0.2.5/ios/Classes/SwiftLibphonenumberPlugin.swift:2:7

Uncategorized (Xcode): Command SwiftEmitModule failed with a nonzero exit code

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps from the photo attached.
[image]